# rte plugin for image not working in richtext in AEM 5.6

Tags: aem, richtext

rte plugin for image not working in richtext in AEM 5.6

I am using the following code

```
{
    "xtype":"richtext",
    "id":"<%= id %>_text",
    "name":"text",
    "enableSourceEdit":true,
    "width":"100%",
    "rtePlugins": {
        "image": {
            "features":"*"
        },
        "misctools": {
            "features":["specialchars","sourceedit"]
        },
        "findreplace": {
            "features":["find","replace"]
        },
    },
}
```

For the given code snippet i am not able to add the misctools and find replace working properly but image plugin is not allowing drag and drop.

It would be really great help.

Comment: Could you possibly provide more information? Are there any errors in the javascript console? How are you deploying this code in your component?

Answer (score 1):

The Richtext image plugin and specialchars plugins seem to only be compatible with Mozilla Firefox on my system. If you're using Chrome or Safari it will be set up correctly but it won't work.

Curious if that fixes your issue.